# DB2 Prechecks in stored procedure using mulitple conditions

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am calling a stored procedure which should make some prechecks.
Currently I am going through all checks. When one check is failed, than it should throw the exception.

How can I realize it?

```
DECLARE VSTRING VARCHAR(1);

SELECT * INTO VSTRING
FROM
(SELECT 'A'
FROM A WHERE ID = xxx)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT 'B'
FROM B WHERE xxx)

IF(VSTRING IS NOT NULL) THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '0101' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Violation ...' || VSTRING;
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a message about a 1-st arbitrary violation with this code.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE VSTRING VARCHAR(1);
DECLARE MSG VARCHAR (70);

SELECT V INTO VSTRING
FROM
(
  SELECT 'A' AS V
  FROM (VALUES 1) A (ID) 
  WHERE ID = 1
UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'B'
  FROM (VALUES 1) B (ID)
  WHERE ID = 1
)
LIMIT 1;

IF(VSTRING IS NOT NULL) THEN
  SET MSG = 'Violation ...' || VSTRING;
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75101' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = MSG;
END IF;

END
```

```
[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0438N  Application raised error or warning with diagnostic text: "Violation ...B".  SQLSTATE=75101 SQLCODE=-438
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PLX9rfGL)

Comment: Oh I need it with `INTO`, just updated my example, because I need the information in the exception.

Comment: SELECT INTO returns an error, if it returns more than 1 row. What are you going to get in this case in the variable?

Comment: I only want to print out the table which has the violation caused, so check for one row is sufficient.
https://dbfiddle.uk/Jo0R9G7X

Comment: Let me ask the same again in other way. What message do you want to get exactly, if you get **more than one** violation? All table names with violations? Any first one only? Something else?

Comment: I want only the message from the first violated table, not all. After first violation match, no more checks needed.

Comment: But `UNION ALL` means that each check is made, means going through all `SELECT` statements. Is it not possible to say to break after the first match and skip the other checks?

Comment: It's possible, of course. Just split your code into a series of a single table `SELECT INTO ...` and `IF ...` pairs.